# разное количество знаков в профиле

Tags: дефект, знаки, профиль-участника

почему у меня в профиле отображается разное количество знаков? Вот сейчас на этой странице справа вверху я вижу 31 и 2, а на другой странице, например, вот на этой - [инициализация массива swift](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711333/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-swift)  ,  в это же время показывает 31 и 6.

Comment: На мета сайте и основном сайте разные профили.

Comment: сори, что может быть вмешиваюсь в вашу внутреннюю кухню, но не запутывает ли это посетителей, особенно новых? По мне так это один ресурс, один сайт.

Comment: На мете обсуждаются общие вопросы, касающееся сообщества. Медальки тут лишь постольку-поскольку.

Comment: спустя некоторое время это конечно понимаешь, но первое время оно как в тумане. И да, медальки они как бы и не сильно волнуют, хотя иногда конечно интересно. Вопрос в другом, что видишь одно и то же на разных страницах показывает по-разному и начинают в голову лезть разные мысли, что здесь что-то неправильно работает.

Answer (score 1):

Сеть Stack Exchange это множество сайтов (в том числе и Stack Overflow и его локализованные версии: русский, португальский и т.п.). На каждом из которых у участника могут быть разные репутация, знаки, избранные метки и т.п. При этом дополнительно выделяются мета-сайты, то есть сайты о главных сайтах. На них нет отдельной репутации, но остальные параметры могут разниться. Это не является ошибкой, так оно задумано и новичкам бывает иногда действительно не совсем очевидно. Для более полного ознакомления см. [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: спасибо, мы все ценим. Но все равно сложновато) пока к этому привыкнешь