# Ссылка на Мету непонятна

Tags: обсуждение, мета, ссылки

На странице Справки сказано, что ссылка на Мету есть на каждой странице внизу. Но я как новый посетитель не мог понять, где она, поскольку там внизу нет слова Мета. Более того на разных страницах она по-разному называется. В одном месте Оставить отзыв, в другом - Связаться с нами. Обычно так пишут для формы обратной связи, а здесь отдельный форум.

Было бы удобнее так прямо и написать, что это Мета. Например, Мета - Обсуждение сайта

Comment: я тоже не вижу на основном сайте ссылку на Мета в footer. Там она почему то "оставить отзыв" называется.

Comment: Сверху надо нажать самую правую кнопку, там будет ссылка на мету

Comment: @jfs потому что так перевели «Feedback», имеющийся в англоязычных версиях сайтов.

Comment: @alexolut: нет на stackoverflow.com "feedback" ссылки¶ Если средствами перевода можно поправить у нас строчку, то для примера можно "обсуждение сайта (Мета)" для заголовка ссылки использовать. Слова "оставить отзыв" и feedback вызывают ассоциацию с https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact ссылкой, а не Мета

Comment: @jfs enSO вообще отличается от остальных сайтов сети. Я говорил про англоязычные *.stackexchange.com в первую очередь. Посмотрите, например, MSE.

Comment: Я много лет не знал что meta вообще существует. И думаю я не один такой

Comment: @Nick довольно странно слышать про "много лет", учитывая ваш стаж чуть более 2 лет на enSO.

Comment: Зарегистрирован да, знаком лет 7-8

Answer (score 1):

Так завелось, что для обсуждения сайта предусмотрен отдельный сайт, он называется мета-сайтом. (См. попутно [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7337/176217) на другой ваш вопрос). Исходная (англоязычная) ссылка на сайт обсуждений называется «feedback», переведено это очевидным образом как «оставить отзыв», хотя здесь мы вольны сделать и иной перевод. Наиболее очевидным образом ссылка на мету видна из верхнего меню:

> [image: мета-ссылка]

А чтобы не было недоразумений со справкой, можно в самой справке дописать текущее название ссылки из подвала сайта. Это на случай, если перевод ссылки как таковой не трогать.

Comment: все понятно. По смыслу feedback чаще переводят как "обратная связь". И второй момент, если вы администрация сайта, то никто вам не мешает что-то изменить, чтобы посетителям было удобнее.

Comment: @maxMas нет, он не администрация сайта, он всего лишь доброволец-переводчик. Администрация сайта вся за рубежом и на русском не разговаривает.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ну ладно, с переводчиком понятно. Но кто мешает русскоязычной администрации русскоязычных сайтов изменить тот же перевод? И вместо чего-то там написать типа "Мета - Обсуждение работы сайта"

Comment: @maxMas: если думаете, что нашли ошибку или хотите сделать предложение: Задайте новый вопрос с метками [\[дефект\] (или \[предложение\]) и \[локализация\]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). См. [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/23044)

Comment: jfs это как-то слишком официально и сложно. Просто пытаюсь понять, люди, которые управляют русскоязычным сайтом, они как-то заинтересованы в улучшении его работы? Как вообще работает эта система?

Comment: @maxMas нажмите на ссылку

Comment: ну да вы правы. Но вот как выглядит эта ситуация со стороны посетителя. Мы с вами здесь общаемся, есть вроде простой вопрос - перевод каких-то пары слов не совсем точно отражает содержание, на которое ведет эта ссылка с переводом. Изменить её пару секунд. Вместо этого посетителю предлагается пойти куда-то, открыть новый вопрос, там все заново подробно описать, выбрать теги и т.д. Не слишком ли бюрократично? Дружественный сайт, о котором идет речь в параллельной теме, имхо, действует как-то иначе.